# Spring rest controller exception handling

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception

How do I configure a single rest controller to handle exceptions for different API calls returning different object types?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Foo> method1() 

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Bar> method2()
```

Let's say both method1() and method2() throws an instance of MyException, then I need to handle them differently the following way:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Foo> handleFoo(Exception ex) {
    //Return foo with error description
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.setError(ex.getMessage());
    //Set f to response entity
    return new ResponseEntity<>(); 
}

@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Bar> handleBar(Exception ex) {
     //Return bar with error description
    Bar b = new Bar();
    b.setError(ex.getMessage());
    //Set b to response entity
    return new ResponseEntity<>(); 
}
```

When method1() throws an instance of MyException, then handleFoo() should be called.
And for method2(), handleBar() should be called.

Is this possible in a single Rest controller or do I need 2 rest controllers for each method?

Comment: In case of exception you don't have to return `ResponseEntity<Foo>` or `ResponseEntity<Bar>`. You can create one Error entity and return it like ResponseEntity<Error>.

Comment: otherwise you throw 2 different exception in each scenario, it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of `@ExceptionHandler` is that you can have the same exception from multiple places handled in a single place. You're looking for the opposite: handling an exception in multiple places/ways.

You can't achieve that within a single class and the annotation, but you can do it with a normal `try/catch` in `method1()` and `method2()`.

Comment: I tried adding a new method (say method2()) to an existing controller and use the same exception handling logic for it. I agree with what you said.